# How to pass multiple entries from one activity to another and save them?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making a food tracking app and want to let the user fill in a food category and food item on 1 activity, submit those and see them on the next activity. They should be able to submit multiple food items and all of them should appear on the second activity. However, only the last one they submit appears on the second activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText fooditem;
Spinner categorySpinner;    
Button submitButton;
Button foodlistButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fooditem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fooditemEditText);
    categorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categorySpinner);             
    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);    
    foodlistButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.foodlistButton);

    foodlistButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String stringCategory2 = categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String stringFooditem2 = fooditem.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("category2", stringCategory2);
                intent.putExtra("fooditem2", stringFooditem2);
                //intent.putExtras(arrayFoodItems); 

                startActivity(intent);

            }

   });
```

This is my code for activity two:

```
public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button submitButton;
Button p2Button;
TextView p2TextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    p2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p2_foodlistTextView);
    p2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.p2_button);

    String category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category2");
    String fooditem = getIntent().getStringExtra("fooditem2");

    if(fooditem != null && !fooditem.isEmpty())
    {               
         p2TextView.append(category + ": " + fooditem + "\n");
    }

    p2Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: what is error in above code? as you are passing only one element in one variable it will pass only that

Answer (score 1):

Create String `ArrayList` and add all the values on it and on submit button click pass  `ArrayList` to another `Activity`

Add values like:

```
List<String> category=new ArrayList<String>();
category.add("First");
category.add("Two");
```

then Pass this `ArrayList` as an **Extras** to another `Activity` and Display it.

Comment: Thank you, I did try to use an array, but was not sure how to pass "infinite" values. How do I make it so I can keep submitting food items and they keep getting added to the array and to the second activity?

Comment: @SoraT. Make singleton class of an `Array` or `ArrayList`. Better to go with `ArrayList`..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not that experienced and my English is not great either. What do you mean by singleton class?

Comment: @SoraT. It means access only static way. Only one time